# Error messages in R when doing a basic heatmap

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is the code:

```
data(attitude)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
qplot(x=Var1, y=Var2, data=melt(cor(attitude)), fill=value, geom="tile")
```

Here is the error that appears:

> Error in .Call("_scales_doColorRamp", PACKAGE = "scales", colors, x,
>   alpha,  :    "_scales_doColorRamp" not available for .Call() for
>   package "scales"

I already tried to delete and reinstall package "scales" or to restart R but with no change.

EDIT: Problem solved. I desinstalled and reinstalled the package "scales" but, this time, when they asked me "Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation?" during the installation, I answer "no". The script works now. Does anyone know why it solved it?

Comment: Your code works for me. Have you tried restarting your `r` session?

Comment: I tried and no change.

Comment: Works fine for me as well. What version of R/ggplot/scales are you using? You can check with `sessionInfo()`

Comment: works for me too.

Comment: @MrFlick: Version 1.0.0

Comment: But what version of ggplot? If you have any other version of ggplot it might not work with the newer scales package.

Comment: The ggplot2 version is 3.1.0